# PSR - "An error occurred while attempting to save the recorded steps"

Tags: windows-7, problem-step-recorder

While using Problem Steps Recorder included in Windows 7, I receive the following error when attempting to stop a recording:

> An error occurred while attempting to save the recorded steps.

So far I've tried going to one monitor, changing the output path to a path in My Documents, and running PSR as an administrator, but I always get the same error message if I've recorded at least one step before stopping the recording (not recording any steps does not result in a file being saved).

How do I get Problem Steps Recorder to successfully save a recording?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My issue was resolved by removing both KB3060716 and KB3071756. Removing one or the other alone did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

remove the following update. this should fix issue.

> >
>   KB3060716
>   >
>   https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/MS15-090

Comment: Welcome to Super User! While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so. Your link does not mention Problem Steps Recorder".

Comment: This did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is an update to the telemetry subsystem that will fix the error. Worked on my 64bits Windows 7 Pro SP1

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3080149

You will have to reboot after aplying it. I prefer moving forward than backward with patches...